# Which (if any) car-sharing companies in Toronto offer one-way return at Pearson Airport, barring car2go?

Tags: car-rentals, toronto

[car2go quit Toronto](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/toronto/car2go-leaving-toronto-1.4675923), but still lets customers "park and fly" in [Calgary](https://www.car2go.com/CA/en/calgary/airport/), [Montreal](https://www.car2go.com/CA/en/montreal/airport/), and [Vancouver](https://www.car2go.com/CA/en/vancouver/airport/).

It's too expensive to rent a car near Finch TTC station and return at the airport, by reason of:

1. $100 Drop Fee, for returning to a different location.
2. airport locations' higher prices.

Comment: It might be cheaper to just take a cab.

Comment: Or depending on where you are and how many of you, cab to Union Station and then UPE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would like to rent a car near home in Toronto to drive to the airport, it may be cheaper and more convenient to use Uber as an option.

In Toronto, there is a great variety of Uber options: starting from Uber Pool cheap for 1-2 people ending with Uber XL for up to 6 people.

Comment: Use the company built on the triple platform of exploiting its drivers ignorance of the costs of driving their own vehicle, the wilfull ignorance of rule of law and the deliberate dismantling all protections organized labor achieved in the last hundred plus years just to save three dollars on the way to the airport!